# Look for the first "_" in a filename string

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through a directory and group files by the filenames up until the first `_` in the filename.

Files are structured by

> Manager Name_Employee Name_Assessment.xlsx

I want this to group together strings up until the first underscore. I can't designate a character length because managers have different names.

I'm thinking changing the `If Right(filename,4)` statement should do what I want, but I can't specify a character limit.

```
Public Sub Move_Files()

Dim sourceFolder As String, fileName As String
Dim destinationFolder As String, foundDestinationFolder As String
Dim missingFolders As String

sourceFolder = "C:\Assessment\"
If Right(sourceFolder, 1) <> "\" Then sourceFolder = sourceFolder & "\"

'Loop through *.xls files in source folder

missingFolders = ""
fileName = Dir(sourceFolder & "*.xls")
While fileName <> vbNullString
    **If Right(fileName, 4) = ".xlsx" Then**
        destinationFolder = Left(fileName, InStrRev(fileName, ".") - 1)
        foundDestinationFolder = Find_Subfolder(sourceFolder, destinationFolder)
        If foundDestinationFolder <> "" Then
            Name sourceFolder & fileName As foundDestinationFolder & fileName
        Else
            missingFolders = missingFolders & vbCrLf & destinationFolder
        End If
    End If
    fileName = Dir
Wend

If missingFolders = "" Then
    MsgBox "All subfolders exist.  All files moved to their respective destination folder"
Else
    MsgBox "The following subfolders don't exist:" & vbCrLf & _
            missingFolders
End If

End Sub
```

After it identifies all that fit within that manager's name, I want to group only those manager's employee files into a folder with their name up until the first `_`.

Comment: Perhaps consider the [`InStr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) function.

Comment: To add to @BigBens comment - `Right(filename,<result of Instr function>+1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If the file extension is `.xlsx`, then change `fileName = Dir(sourceFolder & "*.xls")` to `fileName = Dir(sourceFolder & "*.xlsx")`.
2. Consider the [`InStr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) function, which "returns a Variant (Long) specifying the position of the first occurrence of one string within another."

   - As is, `destinationFolder = Left(fileName, InStrRev(fileName, ".") - 1)` finds everything to the left of the last period.
   - So if you want to the destination folder to be `Manager Name`, then perhaps `destinationFolder = Left$(fileName, InStr(fileName, "_") - 1)`
   - Note that this can be made more robust to handle the possibility of no `_` in the file name, or the file name beginning with `_`, with an initial `If InStr(fileName, "_") > 1)`.

Comment: I edited it to work, but it's running through and not actually making any folders, odd. Well, your answer at least got it to identify the string I want to label each folder with. thanks!

Comment: `Name` doesn't create a new folder, were you expecting it to?

Comment: yeah, would I need to switch that to a `MkDir`?

Comment: You'd have to `MkDir` first yeah, and then `Name` to move the file